# React Native stacking order

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Since there is no zIndex in react-native, we have to make do with `position: absolute` and last element comes to top. Is there anyway to reverse this behaviour. I want the last item to be at the bottom and the first item to be stacked at the top.

I am guessing flex `order` doesn't play nice with react-native.

Think of a swipeable infinite full page width/height news feed. I need the first item to be on top, consequently the items that get appended to the View should be placed beneath.

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have been redirected to this page through a Google search, please know that RN v0.29 and above supports zIndex which solves this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have also been wondering this.  I found a Android only solution.  If you supply Elevation to the views you can stack them in the order you want.  I am unsure how solve this with iOS.

> elevation number (Android-only) Sets the elevation of a view, using
>   Android's underlying elevation API. This adds a drop shadow to the
>   item and affects z-order for overlapping views. Only supported on
>   Android 5.0+, has no effect on earlier versions.

Source: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html